# Spring post processors, order, @Required

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, autowired, post-processing

At work we have a custom ServiceProvider pattern with an annotation for binding services with a spring post-processor.

I wonder if i can check if my binding was correctly done, by using @Required.

The binding is not done by Spring (neither xml or autowiring).

I guess if it's possible, the post processor order has some importance (spring checking required should be processed after our custom binding processor).

Can someone tell me if it's possible and how?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll able to use `@Required` for this, since it only checks for property values set as part of the bean definition (I think), not programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is a [`PriorityOrdered`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/PriorityOrdered.html) with order value `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1`. Threrefore your postprocessor need to implement `PriorityOrdered` with the lesser order value to be fired before `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.